# Настройка 5го слайда в PureCSS слайдере

Tags: css

Взял с codepen pureCSS слайдер, но не могу настроить отображение пятого слайда. По видимому надо настраивать keyframe, но не могу понять как.

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
}


/* Slider */

#slider {
  width: 546px;
  height: 398px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes load {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.slides {
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: slide 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 30s infinite;
  animation: slide 30s infinite;
}

.slider {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Legend */


/* Contents */

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-txt {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 265px;
  -webkit-animation: content-s 7.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: content-s 7.5s infinite;
  animation: content-s 7.5s infinite;
}

.content-txt h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content-txt h2 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16x;
  font-style: bold;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 30px;
}


/* Switch */

.switch {
  width: 120px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 30px;
}

.switch > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.switch > ul > li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.on {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #867550;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: on 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation: on 30s infinite;
  animation: on 30s infinite;
}


/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes content-s {
  0% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0;
  }
  80% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  90% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -550px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes content-s {
  0% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0;
  }
  80% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  90% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -550px;
  }
}

@keyframes content-s {
  0% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  15% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0;
  }
  80% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  90% {
    left: -550px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -550px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes on {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes on {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}

@keyframes on {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  21% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  46% {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  71% {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
  96% {
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <!-- Первый слайд -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-txt">
          <h2>Не хотите тратить время на изучение предложений от страховых компаний?</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/1.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Второй слайд -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-txt">
          <h2>Мы предложим индивидуальные условия по страхованию вашего бизнеса</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Третий слайд -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="legend"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-txt">
          <h2>Мы поможем Вам сократить затраты на страхование</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/3.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Четвертый слайд -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-txt">
          <h2>Мы поможем защитить Ваш бизнес от неблагоприятных погодных условий</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- Пятый слайд -->
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="content-txt">
            <h2>Мы подберем оптимальную страховую защиту для Вас и вашей семьи</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/5.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
нарушена хтмл структура слайда... закройте див 4го слайда до начала пятого


0%,
100% {
margin-left: 0%;
}
21% {
margin-left: 0%;
}
25% {
margin-left: -100%;
}
46% {
margin-left: -100%;
}
50% {
margin-left: -200%;
}
71% {
margin-left: -200%;
}
75% {
margin-left: -300%;
}
96% {
margin-left: -300%;
}
```

тут описано только 4 сдвига, добавте просто пятый

http://broker-sberbank.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/3.jpg - эта картинка подозрительно долго грузится даже если на прямую заходить, я предполагаю что у нее подменен хедер - это может быть причиной, попробуйте пересохранить его через фотошоп и залить  на сервер, она просто не успевает подгрузится в слайдер...

Comment: Именно с 3й? Что значит "подменен хедер" у картинки?

Comment: картинку могли просто переназвать изменив родимое расширение например на .jpg - а в хедерах картинки оно то всеравно останется старым...поэтому пересохранять онли через фотошоп

Comment: вы пересохранили картинку? сейчас слайдер адекватно работает...

Comment: Мммм. Нет, не трогал. Вроде в "свойствах" заголовки и всякая инфа только у "скрытого 5го слайда".

Comment: Изначально все картинки обрабатывал в ФШ, и сохранял в .jpg

Comment: дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Не могу понять как разделить. Пробую вот так: `@keyframes slide{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  16%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  20%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  40%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  44%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  64%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  68%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
  78%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
  82%{
    margin-left:-400%;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:-400%;
  }
}`   И после 4-го слайда пустое место появляется + текст медленно выползает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41146/discussion-between--and--).